# Using a python decorator to authenticate

Tags: python

I have been trying to learn python decorators and wrote the following code. But it keeps giving errors.

```
import os
import sys

def authenticate(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):
        euid = os.geteuid()
        if euid != 0:
            print "This command requires privliged mode. Enter password.."
            args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
            os.execlpe('sudo', *args)
        fn(*args)
    return wrapper

@authenticate
def show_files(dir):
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir)]
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            print file

dir = raw_input("Please enter a directory name\t")
show_files(dir)
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "auth1.py", line 24, in show_files(dir)
    File "auth1.py", line 11, in wrapper fn(*args)
    File "auth1.py", line 16, in show_files files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir)]
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

---

The idea is to run the `show_files` function only to users who could authenticate themselves. My problem seems to be the way authenticate is written and the `execlpe` call. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to show the actual, complete error messages.

Comment: What directory are you entering at the prompt?

Comment: I entered /tmp. I think the problem is execlpe call. I do not think I understand it completely. Is dir and *args end up being the same ?

Comment: Downvote for the weird programming approach. Sudo outside the script but not inside...this makes me cry.

Comment: Why do you override *args*?

Comment: Mr. CRUSADER, could you explain what you mean by your statement. How can I call sudo inside the script. Is there a way to do so in Python ? Remember I am a complete python newbie.

Comment: I thought the real crusaders did not cry that early.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the problem is with the decorator syntax or with the execlpe/sudo part? Try to tackle one of these challenges at a time. Your decorator looks good though, unless I'm missing something there - I didn't try to run the code.

Good luck!

Uli

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine. Thanks to those who replied in a helpful way.

## !/usr/bin/python

import os

import sys

def authenticate(fn):

```
def wrapper():

    euid = os.geteuid()

    if euid != 0:

        print "This command requires privliged mode. Enter password.."

        os.execvp("sudo", ["sudo"] + sys.argv)

    fn()

return wrapper
```

@authenticate

def show_files():

```
dir = raw_input("Please enter a directory name\t")

files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir)]

for file in files:

    if os.path.isfile(file):

        print file
```

show_files()